# Disable MipMapping

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

how do i disable mipmaping in OpenGL ES (iPhone)?

it should be smth. with glTexParameteri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```